# How to get click event for datagridview created at run time in vb .Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW As New DataGridView

SQL_CMD_TXT = " SELECT `EMPLOYEE_ID`,`NAME` FROM `employees`;"
EMPLOYEE_CENTER_FRM.Controls.Add(OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW)

With OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW
    .Size = New Size(171, 181)
    .Location = New Size(12, 141)
    .BackgroundColor = Color.PeachPuff
    .RowHeadersVisible = False
End With
```

All code is working fine, now only what I want when application is running I'm not able to get text from `datagridview` when its been clicked on any cell. 
There is a `textbox` I want when dynamically created `datagridview` is clicked so selected text automatically transferred to `textbox`.
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please don't write a question in all caps. It's much harder to read. Just write normally. Also, you handle events of all controls created at run time in the same way. If you made the effort to search for "how to handle events of controls created at run time" then you find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, first of all, I tried searching for the literally whole day but still I am not able to understand as u said we can normally handle the event but I am trying this
rivate Sub OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.CellContentClick
        DEL_NAME_TXT.Text = OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()

    End Sub
but i have errors as event and code both not correct, please guide

Comment: Really appreiciate your help i have been to that Microsoft docs many time but that also couldn't helped me but I found the problem the only reason was I had to assign a name to the controller as doing so solved the whole problem

Comment: That is almost certainly wrong. I'm guessing that your issue was how to reference the control that raised the event from code within the event handler. In that case, research would have shown you that the `sender` parameter in an event handler is ALWAYS a reference to the object that raised the event, so you can ALWAYS use that to reference that object under any circumstances.

Comment: DEAR  jmcilhinney
let me explain what was happening, i was trying to add click event for datagridview but i wasn't assigning name for the datagridview object so the addhandler function was returning an error and was not accepting the values so finally assigning a name to the object made addhandler works
"AddHandler OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.Click, AddressOf MYDATAGRIDVIEW_CLICK"
before that i was trying "AddHandler OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.Click, AddressOf  OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW_CLICK" so i was receiving the error
it's solved now I really thank for ur help and interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmcilhinney thanks for your help
here is the code that worked for me:

```
Public OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW As New DataGridView

SQL_CMD_TXT = " SELECT `EMPLOYEE_ID`,`NAME` FROM `employees`;"
EMPLOYEE_CENTER_FRM.Controls.Add(OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW)

With OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW
    .Size = New Size(171, 181)
    .Location = New Size(12, 141)
    .BackgroundColor = Color.PeachPuff
    .RowHeadersVisible = False
    .name=" MYDATAGRIDVIEW"
End With

AddHandler OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.Click, AddressOf MYDATAGRIDVIEW_CLICK

    Public Sub MYDATAGRIDVIEW_CLICK(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
           msgbox(OBJECT_DATAGRIDVIEW.CurrentCell.Value.ToString())
    End Sub
```